# Does Haml supports quantifiers?

Tags: haml

I'm just discovering Haml, and I was wondering if there was anthing like quantifiers.

I tried to find something about it in Haml documentation, without success. I was thinking about something like this:

```
.container
  %p(*5) Lorem ipsum
```

For this, the input would be:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Does Haml supports anything like this?

Comment: What do you mean by quantifier here, what output are you looking for?

Comment: @matt I added the expected input for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haml doesn’t have a syntax like you describe, but you can [run code with `-`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_).

You could achieve your example with something like:

```
.container
  - 5.times do
    %p Lorem ipsum
```

This is Ruby code, you will likely need to vary it if you are using a different Haml implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only way is

```
- 5.times do
  p Lorem ipsum
```